# Where to place the clientaccesspolicy? silverlight + WCF on local

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I have a silverlight application which has a WCF in it. when I try to run the silverlight and call the WCF in fail in communication exception. I've understand that I have to add a client access policy file but I don't know where.
when the silverlight is running it runs this path:

```
SilverlightApplication1\SilverlightApplication1\Bin\Release\SilverlightApplication1TestPage.html
```

and this is from the web.config of WCF:

```
<services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="FileUpAndDownload.Web.MapServiceBehavior" name="FileUpAndDownload.Web.MapService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MapBinding" contract="FileUpAndDownload.Web.IMapService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
```

where do I have to place the clientaccesspolicy file?

Note: both silverlight and WCF are running on local.

thanks!

Comment: If both Silverlight and WCF are running on local, you don't need any clientaccesspolicy file yet, the clientaccesspolicy file is used for cross-domain security concerns. Maybe there is some other error, because the error from not having the clientaccesspolicy in place on the server is more explicit regarding the cause of the error. So check other errors using Fiddler or something like that http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

Place clientaccesspolicy.xml in root of your app. For Cassini it should be ..\bin\release\clientaccesspolicy.xml, for IIS place it in ..\inetpub\wwwroot\yourapp\clientaccesspolicy.xml. More on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm more then sure that you do not need a ClientAccessPolicy if you are running everying on a local machine. But if you do - put it in your root folder. The problem is likely to be in a mismatch between your web and client configs, or just things in your web.config that you do not need that might be causing communication fails. Try to get rid of stff like Mex binding that you do not need and see if you can get it working with minimal configuration.

I saw another one of your question about the same from a week ago that had your client.config file in it. I can say that I was not able to get my own application to work untill i fixed mismatching contract names in the endpoint configurations. Try this:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MapBinding" contract="FileUpAndDownload.Web.MapService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
```

Notice the I is gone in your contract, hope it helps =)

Comment: It doesn't help... Any other suggestion?